# Line by line input sum

Tags: python, list, variables, input

Beginner question

I have an input like this:

```
5 8 9 2 1    # = 25
1 2 0 1 9    # = 13
5 7 9 10 2   # = 33
```

That is separated per lines and between values/individual inputs we have an space.

I need to write code that stores the sum of these values line by line and store them into a variable, like `a1 = the sum of input line 1`, `a2 = the sum of input line 2`.

`a1` will be 25, `a2` will be 13, and `a3` will b 33.

Which function i use to write this the way that I want?

**Extra question:** How to store them individually in a list or a variable? Like, `a1` = the inputs in the line1, `a2` = inputs in the line2, without adding them, I can only do this with lists?

Comment: `a = [sum(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n_lines)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def main():
    a = input()
    l = list()
    total = 0
    while a != 'e':
        for token in a.split():
            try:
                total += int(token)
            except ValueError:
                return -1
        l.append(total)
        total = 0
        a = input()
    print(l)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

... type 'e' as input to quit.

If you enter a non-numeric character (like a letter) the function automatically quits and the program ends.

Comment: Even though I agree this is a good *functional* way to solve it. But not sure why it needs to *expand* OP's orig. requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Just as previous post suggested, here to summarize it - it's easy to break down line by line if you know the mechanic.

When you read input numbers, they are separated by space, and they're strings. So you have to do *split()* then convert to *integer* by using *map.*

Notes - Credit to @Mechanic.  *Labor is mine .*.. ;-)

```
a1 = sum(map(int, input().split()))    # enter input sep. by space, so it need to split first and convert from string to int
a2 = sum(......)                       # sum(generator expression here...)
a3 = sum(.......) 

# Or you just want to save the list of numbers first:
a1 = list(map(int, input().split()))      # save all numbers into a list

# then do the sum() later - if you need to
a1_total = sum(a1)
```

Comment: `map` does not return a list, but an inert iterable object. You need to convert it with `list`.